# Can I modify Django form data and post back to the page?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I want to use a django form, update some of the fields on POST (to the same page) and display the updated field values.   There is no db involved here.

I have a Django form.  I am following the documentation here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/)

Here is my view code:

```
def QuestionView(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == "POST":
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            query = form.data["question"]
            result = chat(filepath=filepath, query=query)
            form.cleaned_data["answer"] += query result["answer"]
            form.cleaned_data["confidence_score"] = result["score"]

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = QuestionForm()

    return render(request, "home.html", {"form": form})
```

Here is my form code:

````
class QuestionForm(forms.Form):
    question = forms.CharField(label="Question", required=1, max_length=255)
    answer = forms.CharField(label="Answer", required=0, max_length=16384)
    confidence_score = forms.IntegerField(label="Confidence", required=0, min_value=0, max_value=100)```
````

The line
`result = chat(filepath=filepath, query=query)`
is an external function that successfully returns an array of values.  I can assign these values successfully to the form.cleaned_data.

I cannot then render the updated cleaned_data back to the form.
Am I going completely down the wrong route or have I just missed an important detail?

Trying to use Django Forms to submit a form, change some of the values and post back to the page.
I am expecting the changed values to appear but they dont.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update or do something to the data before saving you can try this out.

```py
def QuestionView(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            query = form.cleaned_data['question']
            result = chat(filepath=filepath, query=query)
            form.cleaned_data['answer'] += result["answer"]
            form.cleaned_data['confidence_score'] = result["score"]
    else:
        form = QuestionForm()

    return render(request, "home.html", {"form": form})
```

I am not very sure about the `chat(filepath=filepath, query=query)` and what it's about. Anyway, I think the problem with your code is that you are trying to retrieve the question data from the form using `form.data["question"]`, which is not correct. You should use `form.cleaned_data['question']` instead. I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to fix it in the end.  Use a class based form.  Add a custom post function.  Creating a deep copy of the form makes it mutable.  I'm probably going to get shouted at by Django purists but it seems to work fine.

```
from django.views import View
from django.views.generic import FormView, TemplateView
from django import forms
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
import copy

class MyView(FormView):

    template_name = 'myTemplate.html'
    form_class = MyForm

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()

        #Abbreviated code...
        query = form.data["question"]
        result = chat(query, request) # A function that returns some stuff

        #Here is the magic trick
        #Make a deep copy of the form and it is then mutable
        form = copy.deepcopy(form)
        form.data['answer'] = result['answer']
        form.data['confidence_score'] = result['score']
        form.data['status'] = "Query complete"

        #Then return the deep copy in the context
        return render(request, self.template_name, {"form": form})
```